# Which Stack Exchange site should I go to ask "How To Document a Database"?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

Is there a Stack Exchange site for how to create user-friendly specifications and documentation?

For example, if I was the owner of Northwind Enterprises how would prepare a specification for my database that was readable by end-users and not database specific? Are there examples out there?

Note that I don't actually HAVE the database built - I want to create documentation BEFORE I create the database to perhaps put out to tender.

I'm looking for a site where I can ask Business Analyst type questions rather than programmer/DBA questions.

Comment: I don't think it will be on-topic on [Software engineering.se](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) but it is the closest we have. You might try their Meta or Chat first to check if your actual question would be on-topic there.

Comment: Thanks - I was sort of leaning that way. There is so little information anywhere on the web on how to do a good specification, business rules etc as if you were going out to tender. Lots of information on how to build but not much on how to design.

Answer (score 6):

To me, your question looks similar to [How should I document a database schema?](https://writing.stackexchange.com/q/12587/14426) on Writing Stack Exchange. That site isn't just for creative writing (novels, poetry etc.) but also for [technical writing](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/technical-writing); they have hundreds of questions and answers about that topic.

If your question isn't already asked, be sure to check their [Help Center](https://writing.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) before asking a question.

Comment: Thanks for that - maybe that is the site I should go to. The database I want to document already exists but it's from a vendor and I want to nail down the data requirements ( for example the Land Area of the Property must be > 0) . I did find something here:https://www.healthit.gov/playbook/pddq-framework/data-operations/data-requirements-definition/

Answer (score 1):

I would definitly use [Database Administrators](https://dba.stackexchange.com/).
Reason ... quick resarch:

- [Tracking SQL queries and rows operated on for documentation/audit](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/10008/tracking-sql-queries-and-rows-operated-on-for-documentation-audit)
- [Print table documentation with comments?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/24554/print-table-documentation-with-comments)
- [keeping database columns consistent with documentation](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/10279/keeping-database-columns-consistent-with-documentation)
- [SQL Server DR Plan - Test Documentation](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/1924/sql-server-dr-plan-test-documentation)
- [How to generate documentation from stored procedures?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/99267/how-to-generate-documentation-from-stored-procedures)
- [How to format documentation in MS_Description extendedproperties?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/84280/how-to-format-documentation-in-ms-description-extendedproperties)

Besides this is exact Database Administrators duties.

**NOTE: **But now after checking I also would use https://writing.stackexchange.com/

btw.
After checking here: https://stackexchange.com/sites#professional
I can see descriptions like:

> Writing
> Q&A for the craft of professional writing, including fiction, non-fiction, technical, scholarly, and commercial writing

I wonder, why after entering this site here: https://writing.stackexchange.com/
I do not see the same information somewhere here:
[image]