# Is there a technical writing Stack Exchange site?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

With all the tech sites it would seem logical to have a place where those tasked with explaining that tech to both technical and non-technical audiences can exchange ideas, tips, etc.

Comment: See https://writing.stackexchange.com/tags/technical-writing/info. Related: [Which Stack Exchange site should I go to ask "How To Document a Database"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/359875/289905)

Answer (score 13):

[Writing SE](https://writing.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) takes questions on technical writing too. In fact, there have been initiatives on their site in the past to [encourage more of those](https://writing.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1324/29583).

Comment: Also see https://writing.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92/technical-writing-questions